# Questions about ASP.NET Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am reading a book about ASP.NET MVC using Razor syntax and got confused about some codes that in the book. Just wondering what does that mean

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Cart")) {....})
```

Why use "using" key word here? Can anyone explain to me a little bit, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this scenario, razor will generate following code in HTML

```
<form action="/Cart/AddToCart" method="post">

</form>
```

now with the "using" statement, there are two purpose:

1. to import the namespace
2. declare the variable in the using statement will call iDisposable method when it goes out from the close bracket.

In the above scenario it is just a indication of when to open the form tag and close tag.

ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When using this syntax, closing form tag is rendered at the end of using statement automatically.
You can check the documentation here
[BeginForm Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505244%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Manual http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460542(v=vs.108).aspx

> You can use this method in a using block. In that case, the method renders the closing  tag at the end of the using block.

Answer (score 0):

The `using` statement makes sure to call the `Dispose` method of an `IDisposable` interface.

```
public static MvcForm BeginForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
```

`MvcForm` implements `IDisposable` such that it calls `EndForm` internally. `EndForm` closes the `form` tag and injects any validation fields or required JavaScript.